# Como visualizar el icono de la app en SwifUI

Tags: swiftui

Estoy creando una splashScreen, me gustaria poder mostrar el icono que se asigna dentro de XAssets con el nombre AppIcon

```swift
Image("AppIcon")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    .frame(width: 68, height: 68)
```

No hace nada, me arroja

`No image named 'AppIcon' found in asset catalog for /Users/....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale he encontrado lo siguiente, pero no ser si es lo apropiado que funciona para todo dispositivos, dependiendo de su resolucióne etc...

XCode 15 - IOS16

```swift
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "AppIcon") ?? UIImage())
```